# Migrate MS Access to PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, ms-access

I'm getting data as an Access file.

My application uses PostgreSQL/Java. I'd like to convert the Access database to PostgreSQL.
can any one help me to code this

Comment: show us your code so we may help you

Comment: thanks Nguyen...i have done code to connect ms access and postgres(two seperate connection).i dont know how to continue...how to get the table structure...

Comment: Can you create an ODBC DSN which points to your PostGreSQL db, and then use [DoCmd.TransferDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196455(v=office.14).aspx) from an Access session?

Comment: @HansUp can u explain DoCmd.TransferDatabase it is VB is nt it....  i dont know VB

Comment: From within Access, you would use VBA.  But that is probably not appealing for you either.  There is also a feature,  "export to ODBC", available in the Access user interface which does the same but without needing to use VBA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Access to PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637147/convert-access-to-postgresql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is any simple automatic method. You will have to create ddl statements to make the tables in postgresql (not sure if you can export ddl from access), export the data from access to a csv, and then use postgresql copy from command to populate the tables.

Or you could consider trying this tool:

http://docman.sourceforge.net/home_html/projects/sql/exportSQL3.txt

but it looks like a dev version, it may not be mature.

Comment: I thought you just needed to do a one time conversion. You need to write a java program that will convert MS Access databases to postgresql databases? This sounds like a very big project. I think you need to show us what you've coded so far.

Comment: .i have done code to connect ms access and postgres(two seperate connection).i dont know how to continue...how to get the table structure.

Comment: Neither do I, unfortunately. If this were Oracle you could pull it out of the metadata. I think you need someone who knows access better than  I do.