# Importing data from MS Access db to PostgreSQL db

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, foreign-data-wrapper

I have a table in an MS Access db that I want to export to a PostgreSQL database. Every 2 or so months, I want to move all records from the Access table to a table in Postgres.

Right now, I am using the Export to ODBC option in Access to do this, but every time it exports as an entirely new table in Postgres. Is there a way for me to routinely append the records in the Access table to an existing table in my Postgres database? I have come across the option of a FDW but I am not familiar with how to install/use it.

I am new to using PostgreSQL, and have little to no experience working with databases other than Access, so any input/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could add your Postgres table as a Link Table in Access then just write an INSERT statement to it. [more info here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/24-Using-MS-Access-with-PostgreSQL.html)

Comment: Thank you! It seems obvious now that I think about it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Access to PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637147/convert-access-to-postgresql)